# Cannot set PHP include_path

Tags: php, ubuntu, path, include-path

I have uploaded all my files in var/www/html and in one of my php files I have this line :

```
require_once('libraries/stripe/init.php');
```

the structure of my folders are list this:

```
www
 -html/
       -libraries
           -> Stripe -> init.php
       -register.php
```

I keep getting this error message:

> Warning: require_once(libraries/Stripe/init.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/register.php on line 116
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'libraries/Stripe/init.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/var/www/html/') in /var/www/html/register.php on line 116

my php.ini file used to be like this

> include_path= ".:/usr/local/php/pear/"

but based on some answers here i changed it to

> include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/var/www/html/'

but it's not working!

Edit: in my libraries folder I have file called index.php the content is:

```
<?php 
header("Location: ../"); die();
```

Comment: Please check the file in that path

Comment: @Ramki the file exist in that path

Comment: Try Include_once(path)

Comment: @Ramki still get same error + this line : Fatal error: Class 'Stripe\Stripe' not found in /var/www/html/register.php on line 118

Comment: what is the content of `init.php`?

Comment: check for directory permission. I think it is permission issue, as you have recently updated content of directory so. the new content wont be able to benefit the old directory permission

Comment: @MeeneshJain its 755

Comment: @Blip i don't think it has anything to do with init.php. This was working properly on another server I recently moved it to digitalOcean

Comment: @MeeneshJain can you check my Edit section in the questin please

Comment: can you regive the permission to your html folder and if its local machine give full permission i.e 777

Comment: @MeeneshJain I even gave 777 on server to it but its still giving same error

Comment: @MeeneshJain i think the problem is my Stripe folder is in "s" but I'm using capital "S". is there anyway to make not case sensitive?

Comment: @MeeneshJain Giving 777 permissions on anything is asking for trouble, stop spreading bad advice!

Comment: @HiradRoshandel change your code to use the correct path, specifically the case-sensitive correct path. *nix filesystems are typically case-sensitive. It's best to write your code in the most portable fashion

Comment: @Ja͢ck please read my post what i said in it. if its a local machine, that means your home computer and i just asked him to test. not permanently change the permission. its just testing no bad advice. if you think its bad. i will delete my comments

Comment: @MeeneshJain It would say "Permission denied" if there were a permission problem; and even then, more appropriate permissions should be given, e.g. `a+r`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't leave library paths to chance like that:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/libraries/Stripe/init.php');
```

This would make sure you include the script using the absolute directory path of the *currently running* script.

#### Update

> Failed opening required '/var/www/html/libraries/Stripe/init.php'

Well, then the file is **simply not there**; if this file was generated by some other tool, e.g. `composer`, it would need to be done again on a new server (or ideally at every deployment).

> i think the problem is my Stripe folder is in "s" but I'm using capital "S". is there anyway to make not case sensitive?

File systems under Linux are case sensitive by default (not even sure whether it can be changed) as opposed to Windows. Make sure you use capitalisation consistently.

Comment: still same error : Failed opening required '/var/www/html/libraries/Stripe/init.php'

Comment: does it have anything to do with composer?

Comment: @HiradRoshandel Then the file is simply not there; if you used `composer` to install packages in that *non-standard* directory, then you need to run it again on the other server.

Comment: Urgh, it's case sensitivity. See the comment here ~ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30906376/cannot-set-php-include-path#comment49851702_30906376

Comment: @HiradRoshandel Did you actually use Composer to install the Stripe package?

Comment: @Ja͢ck No but someone was saying it is composer problem

Comment: I fixed the problem. It was just being case sensitive and Curl was not installed

Answer (score 2):

That not what you are looking for. it says that php.ini file can't find the path of the file that you specified. that's why you should use absolute path to the file

```
require_once "path/to/file";
```

Comment: but I had this code on another server and it was working properly! there has to be something wrong in my setting